# iOS Generating Random Test Data

Tags: ios, swift, testing, random, generate

For testing, I needed to generate a list of data values randomly and put them into the models for further use. But I found out that there is no library, which could produce such functionality.

The elegant solution I expected to find had to combine such simple things as:

- the variety of data;
- the variety of methods to reach this data;
- the possibility to change the default data set to the custom one.

Comment: So what is your question? If you are asking for a library recommendation that can meet your specifications, your question is off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I hadn't found the accurate solution, I decided to create my own library (ref. https://github.com/codeitua/ios-data-factory).

There were implemented all necessary methods for data generation (including random names, cities, addresses, dates etc) and data retrieve. And moreover, it has "swifty" interface, which provides comfortable use in every project.

I hope, it will be helpful for everyone, who faced the same problem as me!